# How to dynamically change width of a headline to ensure even line lengths

Tags: javascript, css, web-inspector

I'm trying to figure out how [The Washington Post website](https://www.washingtonpost.com/) forces the main headline to break so nicely no matter the actual text or screen width. From what I can determine, if the h1 has a class of `headline`, its width is dynamically calculated to achieve the effect. I know this is done with JavaScript and imagine it's not hard-coded so how is that width actually computed to be somehow cognizant of how the headline will break (preventing highly variable line lengths, orphans, etc.). I just can't track down the JS that's controlling this functionality.

Here is an example of the page loading normally:

[image]

And an example with the `headline` class removed:

[image]

(You can also notice the difference right when the page loads, presumabley just before the JavaScript kicks in.)

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to repeat your question in the title inside your body description. This allows others to more easily track what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want. Obviously, because some words are longer than others, not all the lines have **perfectly** the same length. This code below preserves the *amount* of line breaks that are created by the browser. Then, it adjusts the line breaks' position to ensure a *more or less* even line lengths.

*P.S.: Try running the below code without JS and you'll see the difference*

```js
let h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
let text = h1.textContent
let splitText = text.split(' ')
let getContentBoxHeight = elem => {
  let elemStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem)
  let elemHeightWithPadding = parseInt(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('height'))
  let elemPadding = parseInt(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('padding-top')) + parseInt(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'))
  return elemHeightWithPadding - elemPadding
}
let getContentBoxWidth = elem => {
  let elemStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem)
  let elemWidthWithPadding = parseInt(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('width'))
  let elemPadding = parseInt(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('padding-left')) + parseInt(elemStyle.getPropertyValue('padding-right'))
  return elemWidthWithPadding - elemPadding
}

// return the number of line breaks created by the browser
let breakPointAmount = (() => {
  let body = document.querySelector('body')
  let dummyH1 = document.createElement('h1')
  let oneLineHeight
  let totalLineHeight = getContentBoxHeight(h1)

  dummyH1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('M'))
  body.appendChild(dummyH1)
  oneLineHeight = getContentBoxHeight(dummyH1)
  dummyH1.remove()
  return Math.round(totalLineHeight / oneLineHeight) - 1
})()

// refine the number of line breaks created by the browser
let breakPoints = (() => {
  let denominator = breakPointAmount + 1
  let points = []
  let h1Length
  h1.style.width = 'max-content'
  h1Length = getContentBoxWidth(h1)
  h1.style.width = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < breakPointAmount; i++) {
    points.push(Math.round(h1Length * (i + 1) / denominator))
  }
  return points
})()

// determine where that same number of break points should go in text
let indexesToBreak = Array(breakPointAmount).fill(1)
let cumulativeLength = 0
let cumulativeText = ''
for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
  let word = splitText[i]
  let calculateLength = word => {
    let body = document.querySelector('body')
    let dummyH1 = document.createElement('h1')
    let length
    dummyH1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word))
    dummyH1.style.width = 'max-content'
    body.appendChild(dummyH1)
    length = getContentBoxWidth(dummyH1)
    dummyH1.remove()
    return length
  }

  cumulativeText += word + ' '
  cumulativeLength = calculateLength(cumulativeText)

  for (let j = 0; j < indexesToBreak.length; j++) {
    if (indexesToBreak[j] === 1) {
      indexesToBreak[j] = {
        index: i,
        currentMin: Math.abs(cumulativeLength - breakPoints[j])
      }
    } else {
      if (cumulativeLength - breakPoints[j] < indexesToBreak[j].currentMin) {
        indexesToBreak[j] = {
          index: i,
          currentMin: Math.abs(cumulativeLength - breakPoints[j])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// insert break points at updated locations into text
let newText = (function() {
  let final = ''
  let itbIndex = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
    final += `${splitText[i]} `
    if (indexesToBreak[itbIndex] && i === indexesToBreak[itbIndex].index) {
      final += '<br>'
      itbIndex += 1
    }
  }
  return final.trim()
})()

// add text with new break points to page
h1.innerHTML = newText
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some Long Title that Requires Line Breaking To Ensure Even Line Lengths</h1>
```

Comment: That's awesome and super useful, thanks! Does this work no matter how many line breaks are needed? I tried it in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChrisBup/pen/eYmxjEE) and it appears to only work when the headline has one line break. Not sure why though.

Comment: @Chris To your question: yes, it should work with any amount of line breaks. Fixed it. Problem was located at `getBoundingClientRect().height`. This returns `padding` + content-box `height`. What we want is merely the content-box `height`.

Comment: @Chris Also adjusted the `width` calculation. Also, I've added this code to my CodePen too. *I hope that you don't mind me taking your comments and styles*

Comment: I don't mind at all @Richard Thank you so much for your extra effort and detailed solution. What a great learning experience!